# Função entrando em loop sem motivo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um *script* para incrementar um valor em um `input` de multiplicação quando `+` ou `-` é pressionado. Está funcionando conforme o esperado desde que não se de *focus* no `input` de multiplicação.

A cada *focus* no `input` o *script* entra em *loop* quando acionado (quando os atalhos do teclado são apertados). Ou seja, se o valor é "1" e pressiona `+` o valor passa a ser "2" como o esperado, mas se da *focus* no `input` de multiplicação e pressiona `+` o valor passa a ser "4" e não "3".

Utilizando o `console.log`percebi que entra em um *loop*, passando de "2" para "3" e repetindo passando de "3" para "4".

```js
//Adiciona ou Subtrai multiplicador com teclado
$("#valorBuscaProduto").focusin(function() {
  $(this).keydown(function(e) {

    //Caso '+' seja apertado
    if (e.keyCode == 187 || e.wich == 187) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var multiplicador = $("#inputMultiplicador").val().replace(",", ".");

      multiplicador = parseFloat(multiplicador);
      console.log(multiplicador);

      multiplicador = multiplicador + 1;
      console.log(multiplicador);

      $("#inputMultiplicador").val(multiplicador);

    }

    //Caso '-' seja apertado
    if (e.keyCode == 189 || e.wich == 189) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var multiplicador = $("#inputMultiplicador").val().replace(",", ".");

      multiplicador = parseFloat(multiplicador);
      console.log(multiplicador);

      if (multiplicador > 0) {
        multiplicador = multiplicador - 1;
        console.log(multiplicador);
      }

      $("#inputMultiplicador").val(multiplicador);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="buscarProduto" class="barraPesquisa" method="post">
  <div id="multiplicador">
    <input id="inputMultiplicador" name="multiplicador" value="1">
  </div>
  <input type="search" id="valorBuscaProduto" name="valorBuscaProduto" placeholder="Buscar Produto">
  <input type="submit" name="submitBuscarProduto" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

Comment: Tentei reproduzir o problema que comentou e não consegui. Poderia verificar se o seu código está completo e buscar elaborar um [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tire o `$(this).keydown(...)` para fora do `("#valorBuscaProduto").focusin()`, apague este último e troque o `this` para `"#valorBuscaProduto"`, ficando apenas com:

```
$("#valorBuscaProduto").keydown(...)
```

Isto porque você está, da forma que está agora, a cada vez que seta o foco em `#valorBuscaProduto`, aplicando um novo manipulador de evento `keydown` neste elemento HTML.

Comment: Realmente, me preocupei em limitar a ação para o `#valorBuscaProduto` que acabei esquecendo que o proprio `keydown` já estaria fazendo isso.